# How to create a tag for specific branch using Jenkinsfile

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a scenario i need to build and push docker file only when tag is build from master branch.

```
stage('Tag') {
      when {
        expression { sh([returnStdout: true, script: 'echo $TAG_NAME | tr -d \'\n\'']) }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          echo "tag"
        }
      }
    }
```

The above code will work.. If at all we create a tag for the develop branch or the test branch even though when condition is getting satisfied. can anyone help me how to over come this issue.

Comment: Could you please clarify what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If it is of any help, this is an except of a sequential Jenkinsfile I use to tag branches on repos. It is a two stage process - find the current commit for the branch and then tag that:

```
        steps.withCredentials([steps.usernamePassword(credentialsId: httpCredentials,
                usernameVariable: 'GITHUB_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GITHUB_TOKEN')]) {
            // Need to do this as a two stage activity (need commit sha) but *warning* this api assumes ref is a branch
            def json_info = steps.sh(script: "curl -X GET -H \"Authorization: token \$GITHUB_TOKEN\" -H \"Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json\" ${httpUrlForHost}/repos/${slugForRepo}/branches/${ref}",
                    returnStdout: true)
            def branch_info = steps.readJSON text: json_info
            def sha = branch_info?.commit?.sha
            if (!sha) {
                steps.error("Unexpected sha for branch ${ref} (${json_info})")
            }
            def jsonPayload = "{\"ref\":\"refs/tags/${new_tag}\",\"sha\":\"${sha}\"}"

            steps.sh "curl -X POST -H \"Authorization: token \$GITHUB_TOKEN\" -H \"Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json\" -d '${jsonPayload}' ${httpUrlForHost}/repos/${slugForRepo}/git/refs"
        }
```